# Why would explorer.exe be trying to contact a Cloudflare IP address?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-firewall, cloudflare

I'm running Windows 10 Home build 1903, and recently started monitoring outbound connections (using Malwarebytes Windows Firewall Control). explorer.exe today attempted to connect to 104.24.102.72, which is a Cloudflare IP address. (This happened while I was using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to modify workspaces, but that might be a coincidence.)

explorer.exe appears to have a valid digital signature chain.

- Is Microsoft known to use Cloudflare as a CDN?
- Could there be shell extensions that are hosted in explorer.exe, whose network traffic is attributed to that executable?

Comment: I believe that is indeed one of MS's ip addresses.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/haMdflO.png) of http://104.24.102.72. A few IP databases also claim it's owned by Cloudflare ([example](https://dnslytics.com/ip/104.24.102.72)).

Comment: It is used for Office 365 and other MS cloud apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the [Windows 10 Timeline feature](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/11/windows-10-tip-go-back-and-forth-in-time-with-timeline-new-in-the-windows-10-april-2018-update/).

If you have web pages in the timeline — i.e. if you've ever opened anything in Edge or Internet Explorer — then whenever you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, explorer.exe attempts show you those pages in little tiles, and that means retrieving previews and/or favicons. Hence the outbound connections to random CDNs.

[image: Screenshot of Windows 10 timeline]

(Note that the timeline does this even if you haven't enabled syncing across devices with a Microsoft account.)

I am very relieved that this is *not* malware tunneling through explorer.exe.